# Merge nearby Contours

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to extract the straight line in the middle or get rid of the contours on the left and right side.

For removing the contours I am thinking of clustering the contours together then extracting each contours separately or i can cluster the contours and label them then remove a particular label, but i don't think it will work as i have large variety of images to deal with.

Secondly, I have to find whether the contours in the middle straight line are connected or not i.e. the line is broken or not in the original image.

Original image:

[image: Original image] [image]

Dilated image:

[image] [image]

After findContours:

[image]  [image]

Comment: is your target region always line-like? If you could detect straight lines in the image, how would you decide whether the straight line in the middle or the straight diagonal line on the right is your target?

Comment: @Micka Yup I had this doubt too, but anyways i gave it a try. No luck.

Comment: @I.Newton I tried the dilate thing and then applying findContours and Convex hull but it ouputs me a black image, do you know why this is happening.

Comment: Erosion-dilation?

Comment: "i have large variety of images to deal with. " Then maybe showing a few more and a clear statement what you want to extract would be nice. "I have to find whether the contours in the middle straight line are connected or not i.e. the line is broken or not in the original image. " Who knows, the line may or may not be broken. What would you say?

Comment: @AnderBiguri yes, i have already tried Erosion followed by Dilation it has definitely made the image smooth and small noise patches are removed but still noise is there. I will try to apply breadth-first search on the line to find if it is broken as the image is only 0 and 255 another thing I am planning to take these images and train a CNN and then classify whether line is continuous or not (Just thinking) because i don't have enough knowledge of image processing to remove the noise and find

Comment: @Trilarion i have added more sample images, thank you for your attention, as i told i am trying to find broken lines in the Dilated images look at the one on the right now in that figure you can see 3 vertical lines on the left side of  3 vertical line you can see 2 horizontal rectangle sort of shapes the rectangle which is towards the bottom of the image has some region missing (this is what i will categorize in broken), now look at the image on the left in dilated image at the middle of that image you'll see a vertical incomplete straight line.again it will be classified as broken.